# Run rand() in C language and loop with Shell Scripts

Tags: c, shell, random

I have a C code file (call "*test.c*" and output is "*test.out*") like below and just a simple output of random number:

```
int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL)); 
    double r = (double)rand() / (double)RAND_MAX;
    printf("%f\n", r);
    return 0;
}
```

and now I use shell scripts to run "*test.out*" 5 times in Linux, the code below:

```
for i in 1 2 3 4 5
do
    test.out
done
```

but the result show like below

```
0.840188
0.840188
0.840188
0.840188
0.840188
```

It shows the same random number.

Answer (score 2):

You initialize the pseudorandom generator using the current time. On most platforms the `time` function returns the current time *in seconds*. If you run this program multiple times in a single second then you will set the same seed in all executions, and get the same "random" number.

Add e.g. a `sleep 1` in the loop in the script and you will see a different result.

Answer (score 1):

`rand()` will produce the same sequence of numbers for the same *seed* (the one you set with `srand()`).

It's very likely that your loop runs too fast and all your runs end up using the same *seed* (i.e. `time(NULL)` returns same value). Hence, you see the same output.

You can `drand48()` instead for producing uniformly distributed numbers. Or if you simply want to test `rand()`, you can just add a delay between your iterations.

Comment: Or just use something other than just the time, like `srand((time(NULL) ^ (getpid() * 40499));`

Comment: In theory, it may still end up with the same sequence numbers (due PIDs reuse). But in practice, it mostly works.

Comment: Amazing `getpid()`! it works! (just in practicc) so is there any theory way to work?

Comment: That would require PID reuse inside a second, which is pretty unlikely. Though, I concede, not impossible.

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in 1 2 3 4 5
do
    test.out
done
```

You execute the program 5 times in the same second, and since you are using system time in seconds as seed for your `rand()` function, naturally, you will get the same results. If you wait a second (or longer then a second) between executions, you will get different values.