# Why is %random% in Windows time based and how to get a real random number?

Tags: windows, batch-file, random, cmd

I use the following script:

```
set /a num=%random% %%1000 +3000
timeout /T %num%
taskkill /F /IM chrome.exe
```

I trigger it using Windows task scheduler on multiple virtual machines at the exact same time.

The problem is: The value is not really random. It feels like it is Windows time based. I get the same value on every machine.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Random generator in the batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19694021/random-generator-in-the-batch)

Comment: Unfortunately not, there is no really a solution. It understand now why its the same "random" number but not really a solution.

Comment: It looks like you’ll need to write a RNG in another language then make use of it in the code

Comment: It sounds like you're asking for a cryptographically strong RNG.  Remember that a tool is only as strong as its weakest component, and command-.BAT is an extremely flimsy component.  If you truly need a strong RNG, try looking into PowerShell, or switch to a language like C#.

Comment: Not really stong, just need smth not time based which isnt random.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use vbscript to get random number & enter your number in `max` and `Min` value :

```bat
@echo off
cd /d "%~dp0"
set /a max=3000
set /a min=1
(
Echo max=%max%:min=%min%:Randomize
Echo WSH.Echo ^(Int^(^(max-min+1^)^*Rnd+min^) + max^) ) >> Vbscript.vbs
FOR /F %%A IN ('cscript //nologo Vbscript.vbs') DO Set RAND=%%A
Del "Vbscript.vbs"
Echo %RAND%
timeout /T %RAND%
taskkill /F /IM chrome.exe
pause>nul
```

Comment: There's no need to write to a vbs file. Just use a [hybrid batch-vbs file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9074476/995714) instead

Answer (score 0):

Use powershell to get the random numbers in a range:

```
@Echo Off
For /F %%a in ('Powershell -Command "& {[math]::Floor(Get-Random -Maximum 3000 -Minimum 1000)}"') Do Set rand=%%a
Echo %rand%
Timeout /T %rand%
Taskkill /F /Im chrome.exe
Pause >nul
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is a **pure batch** solution without any VBS, JScript or PowerShell, but it's *highly recommended to just avoid cmd* with nasty legacy things and just use PowerShell. Things like this never happen on PowerShell

> Why is %random% Windows time based and how to get a real random number?

`%random%` is a special variable in cmd.exe. It has *nothing* to do with Windows itself. It's seeded by the famous classic `srand((unsigned)time(NULL));`<sup>1</sup> like most naive/simple C or C++ code so it can't provide proper random sequences if all of them start in the same second (which is the resolution of `time()` function). There are so many related issues:

- [Run rand() in C language and loop with Shell Scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34082922/995714)
- [Is it possible to increase the refresh speed of srand(time(NULL)) in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30773914/995714)
- [srand(time(NULL)) doesn't change seed value quick enough](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5574914/995714)

The common solution is to use a high resolution time value like nanosecond because it's extremely unlikely for 2 processes to start in the same millisecond or nanosecond. That's still "time-based" but almost all random numbers are [pseudo-random](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator) and seeded with time  like that. There aren't any other good way to get a different seed that changes every time in cmd. You can never get a *real random number* in computers without a real entropy source

You can do a similar workaround by *modifying the value with centisecond* like this:

```bat
set /a "num=(random ^ %time:~-2%) %% 1000 + 3000"
```

Or get *millisecond* like this

```bat
for /F "usebackq tokens=2 delims==" %%i in (
    `wmic os get LocalDateTime /VALUE`
) do @set ctime=%%i
set /a "num=(random ^ %ctime:~15,3%) %% 1000 + 3000"
```

For better results some programs combine the time with the *process ID* so that no two processes have the same seed. You can also do that

```bat
for /f "usebackq tokens=2 delims==; " %%a in (
    `wmic process call create '"cmd.exe" "/c exit"' ^| find "ProcessId"`
) do @set PID=%%a
for /F "usebackq tokens=2 delims==" %%i in (
    `wmic os get LocalDateTime /VALUE`
) do @set ctime=%%i
set /a "num=(random ^ %ctime:~15,3%*31 ^ PID) %% 1000 + 3000"
```

Here a child's PID is used instead of the current PID, but it's the same for this purpose

---

<sup>1</sup> [As random as I wanna be: Why cmd.exe's %RANDOM% isn't so random](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100617-00/?p=13673)