# Weird behaviour of random with double click on batch script

Tags: batch-file, random

I feel very confused right now, I would like to have some insight on what is going on.

I am trying to write a batch script that would launch a random web browser when I double-click the icon. Easy enough.

Here's my first attempt:

```
set /a var=%random% %%7 + 1

if %var%==1 (start "brave" "C:\Program Files\BraveSoftware\Brave-Browser\Application\brave.exe")
if %var%==2 (start "chrome" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe")
if %var%==3 (start "edge" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe")
if %var%==4 (start "firefox" "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe")
if %var%==5 (start "libreWolf" "C:\Program Files\LibreWolf\librewolf.exe")
if %var%==6 (start "opera" "C:\Program Files\Opera\opera.exe")
if %var%==7 (start "vivaldi" "C:\Program Files\Vivaldi\Application\vivaldi.exe")
```

This works perfectly, nothing to complain about.

Now, I wanted to make my random picking a little bit cleaner, so I did this:

```
set /a minval=1
set /a maxval=7
set /a var=%RANDOM% * (%maxval% - %minval% + 1) / 32768 + %minval%
```

And here is where the strange stuff is happening.

When I double-click the icon, it keeps opening the same browser on and on (meaning, and I verified it, that var always has the same value). But when I start the script from the cmd, **it works perfectly, as before**.

What is going on?! How is the first attempt okay but not the second one? And why does it work from the command line and not from mouse input?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is %random% in Windows time based and how to get a real random number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59823766/why-is-random-in-windows-time-based-and-how-to-get-a-real-random-number)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The seed for the random number generator is the current time.

If you turn `echo` on, you'll find that the "random" number generated is changing slowly.

When you start your batch by clicking, a new process is created and the first value returned by `%random%` appears to be the seed, consequently when you apply your formula, the calculated value will remain constant for a substantial time. Using `mod`, the value will change more rapidly.

If you run the same batch multiple times from the prompt, the random seed belongs to the interactive `cmd` session, so the seed is not re-initialised for the next run.

One consequence of this scheme is that if a batch using `random` is executed at the same time of day (like by task scheduler) then the same sequence of numbers will be generated.